# How to specify unique styles for a particular div in shopify for blog posts?

Tags: html, css, shopify, blogs

I am having an issue while assigning style to a particular div in the blog post section of the shopify development store.

The problem is, it is automatically commenting the whole css part even if i removed the comment and save it, it again comments the whole css part.

How can I assign the division a css style?

Answer (score 0):

The Shopify editor can't read all css in style attribute.

You can use a class or an id to achieve this. *example* :

```
<div style="background:yellow">[...]</div>
```

if this don't work, you can add a Class like this :

```
<div class="yourclass">[...]</div>
```

And go in your theme.scss (or main.scss / style.scss depend of your theme) to add style to your element. *example* :

```
.yourclass { background:yellow;}
```